# How to use sage math notebook server using LAN?

Tags: ubuntu, lan, webserver, sage

I am using sage-5.12-linux-64bit-ubuntu_12.04.3_lts-x86_64-Linux in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed in a desktop. I want to run sagemath server in the desktop and to access the notebook server from my laptop.
I have found this [link](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/notebook/sagenb/notebook/notebook_object.html). I tried

```
sage: notebook(interface='', server_pool=['sage1@localhost'],
....:          ulimit='-v 500000', accounts=True)
```

It lets me log on to the Sage notebook server remotely by `desktopLANaddress:8080/` instead of `localhost:8080/home/admin/` but output of any program is not displayed in my browser (latest Firefox). How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

did you set the pair of ssh keys as explained here
http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/notebook/sagenb/notebook/notebook_object.html
under the section INPUT: (more advanced)

I don't know much about this issue
it just happens that I'm trying to do the same thing as you and bumped on your question after googling a bit

regards